# HTTP referrer diagnostic library (Search Engine, keywords)

Tags: java, search-engine, http-referer

I find it hard to believe no free software library exists that get's as input a HTTP Referrer string and outputs meaningful information.

The parsing job here is large and I'm pretty sure no single one can do it "really good" :). 
We need the community patches combined for quality detection.

So, getting back to the subject - Are you aware of such library or do we need to start a project for this?

Thank you,
Maxim.

Comment: Please don't specify a language, we like to guess at what you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are absolutely correct. I've added Java. Even thought, you know, the problem domain here is the knowledge base and the algorithm, which can then be ported to any language one sole might desire.